# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:20.4.0. Android-Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Heyy friends!
I have a problem that it couldn't solve, developing an application in ionic and angular after exporting it to android with capacitor, but I got the following error when exporting the apk.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:20.4.0.

As much as I try to change the versions in the build grandle, the error continues.

I'm grateful if someone helps me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by changing the version from 20.4.0 to 18.0.1.

This error happens when exporting ionic app to android studio with capacitor, I hope it helps someone.